# Nuxtjs async await in a page doesnt work on page refresh

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Am trying to fetch data in the fetch method of my page using vuex and nuxt js but whenever a person refreshes the page it fails but works when i navigate through nuxt navigation

So in my page i have

```
    fetch ({ store, params }) {
        store.dispatch('getJobspecialisims')
    },

   //IVE ALSO TRIED ASYNC
     async asyncData (context) {
        await context.store.dispatch('getJobspecialisims');
    },
```

SO in my vuex action i have

```
   async getJobspecialisims({commit}){
      await axios.get(process.env.baseUrl+'/job-specialisims').then((res)=>{
        commit(types.SET_JOB_SPECIALISIMS, res.data.data)
      },(err)=>{
           console.log("an error occured ", err);
    });
  },
```

Now on my component where am fetching the records

```
<div>
  <li v-for="(specialisim) in $store.getters.jobspecialisims">
    <!-DO STUFF HERE->   
 </li>
```

The http request is nver sent when a person refreshes the browser

Where am i going wrong?
I would prefer the async await method. I uderstand that it returns a promise but i have no idea on how to know when the promise has resolved. Thepage should always await untill the data has been completely ffetched hence ive called the fetch or asyncdata method in my page

What else do i need to add or amend?

Comment: `The http request is nver sent when a person refreshes the browser` is nuxt.js or the browser caching? Did you use the dev tools in the browser (network tab) and see if you have cached results in there? I'm not sure how to check cache settings in nuxt.js but you could start with the browser.

Comment: there are no cached results ive checked

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For async actions, you need to put ***return*** before ***dispatch*** when you call it inside ***fetch*** or ***asyncData***:

```
fetch ({ store, params }) {
  // store.dispatch('getJobspecialisims')
  return store.dispatch('getJobspecialisims')
},
```

Source for this answer: [Problem: Vuex actions, dispatch from page](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1693#issuecomment-331303943)

Anyway, I still don't understand why you used ***await*** with ***then***. If I, I will use ***async await*** like this:

```
async getJobspecialisims({ commit }) {
  const res = await axios.get(YOUR_URL);
  if (!res.error) {
    commit("getJobspecialisims", res.data.data);
  } else {
    console.log(res.error);
  }
}
```